# XPathSelectElement catch null reference exception

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am using XPathSelectElement to get some elements from an XML file. It works when those elements are present in the XML file. If the selected element is NOT in the XML it naturally throws a "Null Reference" exception. Which is fine. I would expect it to do that. However, I want to be able to catch that exception and do nothing if the XPathSelectElement is null.

Code that works as expected:

```
public void LoadBonusDescription()
        {
            string Race = CharRaceSelector.Text;
            string bonus = RequirementsBox.Text;

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load($"{Gamepath}");

            string description = (string)doc.XPathSelectElement($"//RaceID[@id='{Race}']/Bonus[@id='{bonus}']/Description").Value;
            //DescriptionBox is a listBox
            DescriptionBox.Text = description;

            
        }
```

I tried throwing in an `if` statement like:

```
if (description == null)
{
    return;
}
else
{
    DescriptionBox.Text = description;
}
```

But it doesn't hit that part, and throws the exception at the string variable assignment here:

```
string description = (string)doc.XPathSelectElement($"//RaceID[@id='{Race}']/Bonus[@id='{bonus}']/Description").Value;
```

How do I catch the exception BEFORE (or during) the variable assignment in order to run the `if` statement?

If I can't catch it, is there a way to disable the `DescriptionBox` listBox AND NOT turn the text in the box to gray (as it does with `DescriptionBox.Enabled = false;`)?
Basically I want to prevent users from selecting items that aren't available in the XML file.

Comment: var descriptionElement = doc.XPathSelectElement($"//RaceID[@id='{Race}']/Bonus[@id='{bonus}']/Description");

if(description != null && description.Value != null)
{
     DescriptionBox.Text = description;
}

Comment: Just use the [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) `doc.XPathSelectElement($"...")?.Value;`

Comment: Or just use the [explicit string cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.op_explicit?view=net-5.0#System_Xml_Linq_XElement_op_Explicit_System_Xml_Linq_XElement__System_String) on `XElement` rather than getting the `Value` explicitly: `(string)doc.XPathSelectElement($"...");`

Comment: @dbc
 ```
`var description = (string)doc.XPathSelectElement($"//RaceID[@id='{Race}']/Bonus[@id='{bonus}']/Description"); if (description == null) { return; } else { DescriptionBox.Text = description;       }` works perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added:

```
var description = (string)doc.XPathSelectElement($"//RaceID[@id='{Race}']/Bonus[@id='{bonus}']/Description");

            if (description == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                DescriptionBox.Text = description;
            }
```

as @dbc suggested and it works perfectly!